# How to disable debug mode on Vaadin7-UI with cdi

Tags: vaadin

I am using the following:

```
@CDIUI
public class MyUI extends UI {...}
```

deploys fine, runs fine. But: jboss console shows: Vaadin is running in debug mode.

now, with web.xml I know how to disable it, but how about vaadin-cdi? Is there an annotation I can use?

Clarification: I have more than a few UIs in my project and dont want to add a web.xml for each one. I am looking for an @DebugMode(OFF) Annotation or a global system-/server wide parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some months later, but I hope it helps:

---

I'm using CDI-Integration combined with Vaadin 7.1.1. I added a nearly empty `web.xml` to the `WEB_INF` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>App</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

---

After fixing `<display-name>App</display-name>`, the application was deployed as before. In the following I was able to set `<param-value>false</param-value>` to `true`.

Next, there appeared the following output:

```
[com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 
Request for /VAADIN/themes/app/styles.css not handled by sass compiler while 
in production mode
```

If you're using .sass files as I do, you have to [compile them](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20theme%20using%20sass#section-Creating+a+theme+using+sass-Compiling) manually. Note that I stopped trying at this point.

---

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web.xml either with vaadin-cdi. In order to use the CDI with web.xml you need to add another init-param:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyProject UI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Vaadin UI class to use</description>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.myproject.MyprojectUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uiprovider</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vaadin.cdi.CDIUIProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. I know I can do this, but I have a lot of UI bindings and dont want to provide a web.xml mapping for each when I can just add @CDIUI("foo") to my class instead.